# Any recommendation to customize an iPhone MapView?

Tags: iphone, android-mapview

I want to you iPhone LocationManager and display the position using a custom map, different from the one used by MapView. Is there any way to customize the MapView or should I rebuild my own MapView from scratch ?

- Do you think MapView will be open to achieve this kind of customization in a future release of the SDK ?
- Do you have any recommendation to rebuild a MapView from scratch. I will have to divided my map in level and each level in tiles. But should I associate a tile with an UIImage or should I build/manage dynamically an UIImage composed of tiles currently displayed ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you file a bug with Apple, asking for this feature (I already have). In the meantime, I think your best bet is to take a look at the [route-me](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/) library. It emulates the built-in Google Maps application, but uses either OpenStreetMap, Microsoft VirtualEarth or CloudMade as a data source for tiles. You could add support for loading tiles from your own custom service.